# Council chamber action in Village

Tags: village

We've just started to play the [Village](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/104006/village) board game recently with friends and we're not sure about this rule in Council chamber action:

> You may perform the privilege action which is shown below either the current or **a previous stage** of you family member.

Does **a previous stage** mean only one previous stage or all previous stages? In example if I have a villager on the last stage with action "exchange 1 coin to 3 points", can I also choose to take a starting player ring located on the first action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose any previous action. "Previous" just means "something earlier", it doesn't imply "exactly 1 space". The best evidence for this is the fact that it says "**a**" previous space, not "**the**" previous spot. So yes, you can choose start player using a guy at the top.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for the clarification. Might be obvious for a native English speaker. I'll accept the answer when possible.